# React useEffect triggering on unMount when in Production

Tags: reactjs, .net, react-hooks

I am running a React (Typescript) app with a dotnet backend and locally all works alright, but once I deploy it to azure my useEffect hooks start misbehaving. For example, this call:

```
    const getContacts = useCallback(
      () => {
        getAvailablePartnerContacts(id!.toString()).then(
            partnerContacts => {
                const _partnerContacts = partnerContacts.map(
                    pContact => ({
                        value: pContact.id|| "",
                        key: `${pContact.firstName} ${pContact.lastName}`
                    })
                );
                debugger;
                const allContacts = [...contacts, ..._partnerContacts]
                setContacts(allContacts)
                setPreselectedId(props.selectedPartnerContactId || "None");
            })
      },[])
    
    //load data
    useEffect(() => getContacts, [getContacts])
```

works fine under localhost, but in the deployed version this `debugger` only triggers once I hit the back button in the browser. I cannot even reproduce this issue locally. Did anyone have similar experiences?

Comment: might be something happening while building the code? build it locally and see if the same issue occurs. if it does, hit the debugger and see how your code is transformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you are returning the `getContacts` wich means, your are calling it on component did unmount. Consider doing:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   getContacts()
}, [])
```

Comment: I am such a dunce man... Thank you, `useEffect(getContacts, [getContacts])` did it.